# Finding the Maclaurin series

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

Find the Maclaurin series for $f(x)=(x^2+4)e^{2x}$ and use it to calculate the 1000th derivative of $f(x)$ at $x=0$.
Is it possible to just find the Maclaurin series for $e^{2x}$ and then multiply it by $(x^2+4)$?
I've tried to take multiple derivatives and find a pattern in order to express it as a sum, but I can't find the pattern for part of the derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(x^2+4)e^{2x}=(x^2+4)\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(2x)^n}{n!} = \sum_{n\ge 2}x^n\cdot
\frac{2^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}+\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n\cdot\frac{2^n\cdot 4}{n!}=\\
= \sum_{n\ge 0}x^n\cdot
\left(\frac{n(n-1)2^{n-2}+2^{n+2}}{n!}\right)\,.$$

Comment: Thanks Berci, that is super helpful.

Comment: Why can't you keep the limit of the sum 0 and then just combine the two sums that way.

Comment: Because that would give you a sum of the form
$$ \sum_n a_n x^n + b_n x^{n+2} $$
and not a MacLaurin series.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$e^{2x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2x)^n}{n!}$$
Multiply it by $x^2+4$.

Comment: Ok thank you that answers my question